# Python multiple if-else in the same line

Tags: python, if-statement, printing, nested-if

I know this is possible:

```
a, b = 5, 10
print 'a' if a > b else 'b'  # outputs b
```

However, what if I had another variable 'c'? How do I make them print in the same line using the same type of logic as those two variables? 
Something like?

```
a, b, c = 5, 10, 20
print 'a' if a > b elif 'b' if b > c  else 'c'  # is it possible?
```

Just to mention: I know it's a bad practice, I just wanted to know.

Comment: import `this` : "Readability counts."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no `elif`, use `else` multiple times:

```
print 'a' if a > b else 'b' if b > c else 'c'
```

Comment: Or use multiple statements. This can get unreadable very quickly.

Comment: ya... i just wanted to know.